# Учебник по AS

Tags: actionscript

Подскажите хороший учебник по action script (Adobe Flash).

Comment: https://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/flash_as3_programming.pdf очень подробно можно всё найти на этом сайте

Answer (score 0):

[ActionScript 3.0 для Flash. Колин Мук.](http://www.proklondike.com/books/codingproch/actionscript_flash.html)

Answer (score 0):

Колин Мук actionscript 3.0 лучше не видел, знаний даёт массу!